# How do I DM a user when a reaction is added to a message?

Tags: python, discord.py

Combining a user reacting with sending them a DM has had me stumped.

My project works by having an embed that has a reaction added at the bottom and when the user clicks the emoji then it will DM the user a set of instructions (for now I'm just using the word 'Test').

Here is what I have so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.add'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed Title", color=0x6610f2)
        embed.add_field(name="__**Steps to get DM'd:**__", value=""" 
        • Step 1
        • Step 2
        • Step 3
        • Step 4
        • Step 5
        """)
        
        msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F91D')

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.user_id == client.user.id:
        return

    if str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001F91D':
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

        await message.author.send('Test')
```

I'm just not sure how to get the user's ID outside of the on_message() function because the only way I know how to make the on_reaction_add work is in its own client event. I'm not even sure if I'm handling the DM user aspect correctly.

Using the async version of Discord.py

Comment: In your own words, where you have `if payload.user_id == client.user.id`, what is that for? How does it work? Can you think of a way to take advantage of that information to solve your problem?

Comment: If the user reacting to the message is the bot, then return. I imagine I could do something where the ```payload.user_id``` controls the DM functionality since that should have the user ID of the person who reacted. What are your thoughts on that idea? @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Don't ask me; ask the code - by trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `payload`, you should already get a `discord.Member` object you can work with. Try something like

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if str(payload.emoji) == "\U0001F91D":
        member = payload.member
        await member.send('This is a DM to you!')
```

Because your code does not check for the message id, a reaction to ANY message (not just the one you sent) will lead to a response. To prevent this, you can check whether `payload.message_id` matches the id of your bot's message (which you could store somewhere when sending the message).

You also tried to prevent a response to the initial reaction of your bot. Instead of checking for `payload.user_id`, I would suggest

```py
if member.bot:
    return
```

which prevents a response to any bot reacting to your message, including your own.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked flawlessly. I added an ```and``` statement to make sure it would only work for a single message. ```if str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001F91D' and payload.message_id == insert message id here:``` and that worked perfectly as well.